# web3.js: Estimate gas fee on usdt smart contract transfer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I'm trying to estimate gas value in eth, for USDT transfer, but we3.js gives me only IVALID OPCODE error...

code example

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3('https://cloudflare-eth.com/');

const token = new web3.eth.Contract([{
    'constant': false,
    'inputs': [{
        'internalType': 'address',
        'name': 'recipient',
        'type': 'address',
    }, {
        'internalType': 'uint256',
        'name': 'amount',
        'type': 'uint256',
    }],
    'name': 'transfer',
    'outputs': [{
        'internalType': 'bool',
        'name': '',
        'type': 'bool',
    }],
    'payable': false,
    'stateMutability': 'nonpayable',
    'type': 'function',
}], '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7');


const to = '0x....';
const from = '0x.....'
token
    .methods
    .transfer(to, web3.utils.toWei('1'))
    .estimateGas({from})
    .then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
;
```

Error:
[image]

can't find any working example for this. At the end i want to get near same value as metamask gives me...

**UPDATE after Petr Hejda answer**:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3('https://cloudflare-eth.com/');

const token = new web3.eth.Contract([{
    'constant': false,
    'inputs': [{
        'internalType': 'address',
        'name': 'recipient',
        'type': 'address',
    }, {
        'internalType': 'uint256',
        'name': 'amount',
        'type': 'uint256',
    }],
    'name': 'transfer',
    'outputs': [{
        'internalType': 'bool',
        'name': '',
        'type': 'bool',
    }],
    'payable': false,
    'stateMutability': 'nonpayable',
    'type': 'function',
}], '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7');


const to = '0x..';
const from = '0x..'
const value = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'mwei');

web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    .then(gasPrice => {
        token
            .methods
            .transfer(to, value)
            .estimateGas({from})
            .then(estimatedGas=>{
                const txPriceWei = estimatedGas * gasPrice;
                const txPriceEth = web3.utils.fromWei(txPriceWei.toString(), 'ether');
                const txPriceUSD = txPriceEth * 1800;
                console.log({
                    estimatedGas, txPriceWei, txPriceEth, txPriceUSD
                });
            })
        ;
    })
;
```

Now it works, and estimates.. Something. It is near metamask value, but is about 30% less. Where could i miss this 30%?
[image]
[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the values provided in the code, I'm assuming that you're trying to calculate gas fees for transfering 1 USDT on the Ethereum mainnet.

The web3js `toWei()` function convers a number to an EVM-compatible value with 18 decimal places. However, the [USDT token](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) uses only 6 decimals.

Because of this discrepancy, your code is effectively tying to calculate gas costs of transferring `1.000.000.000.000` tokens (`10^18 / 10^6 = 10^12`).

Since the `from` address doesn't have a trillion USDT, the transaction is expected to revert. And, in the underlying low-level EVM bytecode, a revert is triggered by the `IVALID` opcode.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is not showing invalid and gives me some response, but it is not still as in metamask.. I explained in question update. If you could help me, it will be great!

Comment: @kRicha The total fee in ETH is calculated from `gasLimit` (in your snippet as `estimatedGas`) times `gasPrice` (which is driven by market, and every sender can specify their own gas price)... Your node and MetaMask's node are using different `gasPrice` (by the mentioned 30%) - that's why to resulting ETH amount is different... Unfortunately I don't think that there is a way to retrieve the current MetaMask's `gasPrice` to match the calculation.

Comment: So the easiest way will be just add this 30%?

Comment: @kRicha MetaMask uses 3 basic levels of `gasPrice`, they call it "low", "medium", and "high", with the option to set a custom value... Depending on configuration of each MM instance, users can have different default levels... So adding 30% will solve the discrepancy in this specific case but will not solve it for other users... What is your incentive behind needing to have the same value in web3 and MM? Maybe there's another solution to that.

Comment: I need to tell user if he has ok balance for transaction, or he need to add some amount(in value) of eth to his wallet

Comment: @kRicha You can manually specify the `gasPrice` (the custom value that I mentioned in the previous comment) while creating the request to MetaMask. This will override the default value, and this way you have control over the total ETH amount displayed in the MM popup, so you can validate the total amount beforehand. Docs and code example: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html